# How can I select a column dependent of a different columns content or the name of the column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following three dataframes

```
val df_1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("FIDs", "123456")
)).toDF("subComponentName", "FID_HardVer")

val df_2 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("CLDs", "123456")
)).toDF("subComponentName", "CLD_HardVer")

val df_3 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("ANYs", "123456")
)).toDF("subComponentName", "ANY_HardVer")
```

I want to write a function that return a dataframe which adds a column named HardVer with the content of either FID_HardVer, CLD_HardVer, or ANY_HardVer.

Example output would look like this:

df_1

```
+----------------+-----------+-------+
|subComponentName|FID_HardVer|HardVer|
+----------------+-----------+-------+
|            FIDs|     123456| 123456|
+----------------+-----------+-------+
```

df_2:

```
+----------------+-----------+-------+
|subComponentName|CLD_HardVer|HardVer|
+----------------+-----------+-------+
|            CLDs|     123456| 123456|
+----------------+-----------+-------+
```

This is the code that I tried up unil now but it seems like spark can't handle this type of request since it validates the column even if the condition does not fit.

```
def addHardVer(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._
    val df_withHardVer = df
      .withColumn("HardVer",
        when($"subComponentName" === "FIDs", $"FID_HardVer")
         .when($"subComponentName" === "CLDs", $"CLD_HardVer")
         .when($"subComponentName" === "ANYs", $"ANY_HardVer")
          .otherwise(lit("unknown"))
    )
    return df_withHardVer
  }
```

This throws an exception

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`CLD_HardVer`' given input columns: [subComponentName, FID_HardVer];;

Comment: I suspect the exact behavior you are trying to achieve is not possible with spark. Spark runs an SQL query optimizer on your query, so to do that it needs an internal model for the query that is more limited than just raw Scala code. Columns that might or might not exist are not part of that model. This means you may be better off reformulating your problem to a more SQL-friendly model. But since I do not know what you are ultimately trying to achieve, I'm not sure what that would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a check of whether the column exists in the dataframe?

```
def addHardVer(spark: SparkSession, df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._
    val df_withHardVer = df
      .withColumn("HardVer",
        when($"subComponentName" === "FIDs", if (df.columns.contains("FID_HardVer")) $"FID_HardVer" else lit("unknown"))
       .when($"subComponentName" === "CLDs", if (df.columns.contains("CLD_HardVer")) $"CLD_HardVer" else lit("unknown"))
       .when($"subComponentName" === "ANYs", if (df.columns.contains("ANY_HardVer")) $"ANY_HardVer" else lit("unknown"))
       .otherwise(lit("unknown"))
    )
    return df_withHardVer
  }
```

Comment: I was thinking of something really similar to your solution. You can see it as an answer below. Yours looks a lot better though therefore I am going to accept your answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out that gives me the wanted output but it does not seem like a really nice solution. Any comments on this would be helpful.

```
def addHardVer2(spark: SparkSession, df:DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._
    if(hasColumn(df, "FID_HardVer")){
      print("A")
      df.withColumn("HardVer", $"FID_HardVer")
    }
    else if(hasColumn(df, "CLD_HardVer")){
      print("B")
      df.withColumn("HardVer", $"CLD_HardVer")
    }
    else if(hasColumn(df, "ANY_HardVer")){
      print("C")
      df.withColumn("HardVer", $"ANY_HardVer")
    }
    else{
      print("D")
      df.withColumn("HardVer", lit("unkown"))
    }
  }

def hasColumn(df: DataFrame, path: String) = Try(df(path)).isSuccess
```

Comment: looks similar to my answer. you can use `df.columns.contains("FID_HardVer")`. no need for something like `hasColumn`.